# bourne shell script

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm trying to convert this line of C program to bash script:
C:

```
bin = bin+d*10^n-1;
```

bin,d,n are declared as int.
bash:

```
bin=`exp $bin+$d\*10^n-1`
```

but it's incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Bash has built-in functionality for arithmetic expressions. The feature is called "Arithmetic Expansion". The bash man page contains more information.

The syntax is $((expression)). In your case the script might contain the following.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

bin=1
d=2
n=3
echo $((${bin} + ${d}*10^${n}-1))
```

The operator precedence resembles C's but is not exactly the same, as Bash and C support different operators. Here is a useful reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic

The above is appropriate only because the operands are C ints. Arithmetic Expansion does not support floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: `^` in C isn't exponentiation.

Comment: I have corrected the response.

Comment: How to do it without echo command?

Comment: @TuNguyen `echo` was used to print the result immediately. You can store it in variable like `bin=$((${bin} + ${d}*10^${n}-1))` and then print it using `echo $bin` or use anywhere else.